# Set initial class variable from axios request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

When i call this function

```
getQuestions = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    const { data } = this.props

    axios
        .get(data.questions)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                questions: res.data,
            })

            this.initialQuestions = res.data
        })
        .catch((err) =>
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                questions: [],
            })
        )
}
```

it updates the array `questions` in state and array `initialQuestions` variable in constructor. The state `questions` represents the values form inputs. The inputs are handled in child component with this code

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const { hasChanged, setQuestions } = this.props

    // Update questions
    let questions = this.props.questions
    questions[e.target.getAttribute('data-id')][e.target.name] =
        e.target.value
    setQuestions(questions)
}
```

`setQuestions` is passed in props as `setQuestions={(state) => this.setState({ questions: state })}`
So when i change the value of inputs the `onChange` function is called and it changes the parent component `questions` in state. But the parent variable `this.initialQuestions` also is being changed to the `questions` value from state, but I don't know why

Edit:

That's the code you should be able to run

```js
const { Component } = React;
const Textarea = "textarea";

const objectsEquals = (obj1, obj2) =>
    Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length &&
    Object.keys(obj1).every((p) => obj1[p] === obj2[p])

class QuestionList extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        questions: PropTypes.array,
        removeQuestion: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        hasChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        setQuestions: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.questions = props.questions

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        const { hasChanged, setQuestions } = this.props

        // Update questions
        let questions = this.props.questions
        questions[e.target.getAttribute('data-id')][e.target.name] =
            e.target.value
        setQuestions(questions)

        if (hasChanged && this.questions.length > 0) {
            // array of booleans, true if object has change otherwise false
            const hasChangedArray = this.props.questions.map(
                (_, index) =>
                    !objectsEquals(
                        this.questions[index],
                        this.props.questions[index]
                    )
            )
            console.log("hasChangedArray = ", hasChangedArray)
            console.log("this.questions[0] = ", this.questions[0])
            console.log("this.props.questions[0] = ", this.props.questions[0])

            // If true in array than the form has changed
            hasChanged(
                hasChangedArray.some((hasChanged) => hasChanged === true)
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { removeQuestion, questions } = this.props

        const questionList = questions.map((question, index) => (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
                <div className="card__body">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-7">
                            <div className="form-control">
                                <label className="form-control__label">
                                    Question:
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id={`question-${index}`}
                                    data-id={index}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    name="question"
                                    value={
                                        this.props.questions[index].question
                                    }
                                    className="form-control__input form control__textarea"
                                    placeholder="Pass the question..."
                                    rows="3"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-control">
                                <label className="form-control__label">
                                    Summery:
                                </label>
                                <Textarea
                                    id={`summery-${index}`}
                                    data-id={index}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    name="summery"
                                    value={this.props.questions[index].summery}
                                    className="form-control__input form-control__textarea"
                                    placeholder="Pass the summery..."
                                    rows="3"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))

        return questionList
    }
}

class Questions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.initialQuestions = []

        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            questions: [],
            hasChanged: false,
        }

        this.getQuestions = this.getQuestions.bind(this)
        this.resetForm = this.resetForm.bind(this)
    }

   resetForm = () => {
        console.log("this.initialQuestions =", this.initialQuestions)
        this.setState({
            questions: this.initialQuestions,
            hasChanged: false,
        })
    }

   getQuestions = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        const { data } = this.props

        // axios
        //  .get(data.questions)
        //  .then((res) => {
        //      this.setState({
        //          loading: false,
        //          questions: res.data,
        //      })

        //      this.initialQuestions = res.data
        //  })
        //  .catch((err) =>
        //      this.setState({
        //          loading: false,
        //          questions: [],
        //      })
        //  )

       // You can't do a database request so here is some example code
       this.setState({
           loading: false,
           questions: [
               {
                   question: 'example-question',
                   summery: 'example-summery',
               },
               {
                   question: 'example-question-2',
                   summery: 'example-summery-2',
               },
           ],
       })

      this.initialQuestions = [
          {
              question: 'example-question',
              summery: 'example-summery',
          },
          {
              question: 'example-question-2',
              summery: 'example-summery-2',
          },
      ]
    }

   componentDidMount = () => this.getQuestions()

   render() {
      const { loading, questions, hasChanged } = this.state

      if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

      return (
          <form>
                <QuestionList
                    questions={questions}
                    hasChanged={(state) =>
                        this.setState({ hasChanged: state })
                    }
                    setQuestions={(state) =>
                        this.setState({ questions: state })
                    }
                />


                <button
                    type="reset"
                    onClick={this.resetForm}
                    className={`btn ${
                        !hasChanged
                        ? 'btn__disabled'
                        : ''
                    }`}
                >
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className={`btn btn__contrast ${
                        !hasChanged
                            ? 'btn__disabled'
                            : ''
                    }`}
                >
                    Save
                </button>

          </form>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Questions />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: May you add a little more code to this so we can run it ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both state questions and class variable initialQuestions hold reference of `res.data`. Now when you update questions in `onChange` method, you are updating it by reference i.e directly mutating it and hence the class variable is also updated

You must not update it by reference but clone and update like below

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const { hasChanged, setQuestions } = this.props

    // Update questions
    let questions = this.props.questions
    questions = questions.map((question, idx) => {
        if(idx === e.target.getAttribute('data-id')) {
             return {
                ...question,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
             }
         }
         return question;
    });
    setQuestions(questions)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for knowledge, but your code throws an error. questions is array not object

Comment: updated ans, considering questions to be an array

Comment: `question` is an object and should be spread back into the copy. eg. `return { ...question, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }` (added the spread operator)